# How do I use substr() to extact a vector of cards if the suit is hearts?

Tags: r

I am writing a function that chooses 10 random cards from a deck and then I have to count how many cards of the suit of hearts.  I am stuck on using substr() as we were told it can help us, but I don't know how to properly utilize it.

the card vector is

```
cards <- 
  paste0(c("A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "T", "J", "Q", "K"),
         rep(c("H", "C", "S", "D"), each = 13))
```

and what I did so far

```
drawCard <- function(x){
  
 x <- sample(cards, x, replace = F)
  
  
 print(x)
 

 heartCount <- length(substr((" H"),2,2))
 
 print(heartCount)
 

}


drawCard(10)
```

It works globally, but I cant seem to target the cards I chose at random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give what you want. I modified your function to have two arguments `df` and `nsample`. The idea is you first `substr` the second character of your sampled cards and then you need to check if they are "H" (`==`). In the last, use `sum` to count how many are "H".

```
drawCard <- function(df, nsample){
  sample <- sample(df, nsample, replace = F)
  heartCount <- sum((substr(sample, 2, 2) == "H"))
  # print(sample) 
  return(heartCount)
}

drawCard(cards, 10)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I have been trying to figure this out for some time.

Comment: Glad it helps! :)